# Add pivot table in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, automation, pivot-table

I am trying to add a pivot table in excel using python script with pandas but not able to do so.
I won't to count number of missed and met entries for each priority.

Excel script:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Priority': ['p1','p2','p3','p2','p3'],'SLA': ['Met','Missed','Missed','Met','Missed']})
```

Excel data:

| Priority | SLA |
| --- | --- |
| p1 | Met |
| p2 | Missed |
| p3 | Missed |
| p2 | Missed |
| p3 | Missed |

desired output:

| Priority | Met | Missed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1 | 0 |
| p2 | 1 | 1 |
| p3 | 0 | 2 |

I tried different combination\approach with

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index='Priority',columns=['SLA'])
```

but couldn't get it right. I am struggling hard for this. I am trying this first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to understand how [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) works in order to solve this problem.

First, it has three different inputs:

1. Values -> the values on which the aggregation happens. In this case, it is SLA.
2. Columns -> the new columns that are to be created. In this case, it's SLA's values.
3. Index -> the rows that are to be kept. In this case, it's Priority.

---

Let's convert this into code.

```
df.pivot_table(
  # SLA's values as the columns
  columns=df['SLA'].values, 

  # Priority as the rows.
  index=['Priority'], 

  # SLA's values as the values to be aggregated upon (counted).
  values=['SLA'], 

  # Count is our aggregate function
  aggfunc='count'
).fillna(0).astype('int') # Then we fill NaN values with 0, and convert the df -> int
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad Ayoub, this solution works as required.